# Boost::format hex output

Tags: c++, boost, string-formatting

I'm using boost::format to create and format a string.

I would like to create following output:

> Data: 0x64 - Name: 'xxx', Value: 10

I tried it with following line:

```
boost::format("Data:  %|02x|%1% - Name: '%2%', Value: %3%") % code % name % value);
```

but it doesn't work.

I know that the formation of the first parameter is wrong, but I am not able to fix it.

Is there a possibility to print the first parameter as hex?

Answer (score 12):

Just use

```
boost::format("%1$#x")
```

this means - output first argument in hex form with numerical base.

More information [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives)